# Porting Windows 8 Metro App to Windows 8 phone App- identify API that are not implemented

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am porting a Windows 8 Metro application to a Windows 8 Phone app.
While the Win 8 phone app compiles, there are many API's which throw the API not implemented exception at runtime.

Is there a way to identify all the API's that are not implemented in an existing source?

The only way I can think of doing is to identify all API's being used in my app and then check if that API is supported or not.

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 0):

MSDN will specify if a given API is not implemented.

It will have a section like this: (for example see [this page which is a common example)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.fullname).

> **Remarks**
>
> Windows Phone 8
>
> This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called.

It's quite confusing as lower down the page says...

> **Minimum supported phone**  Windows Phone 8

... but that's misleading as you have found already.

I think tooltips from Intellisense may help you as well from within Visual Studio.